# What is the difference between some similar selenium waits?

Tags: python, selenium, expected-condition

Simple question:

What is the exact difference between those two statements:

1. `WebDriverWait(self._driver, WEB_WAIT_TIMEOUT).until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located(element))`

and

2. `WebDriverWait(self._driver, WEB_WAIT_TIMEOUT).until_not(ec.presence_of_element_located(element))`

In both cases, selenium behavior is the same in my situation.
Thanks in advance

Thanks for responses
Ok but there are still things I dont understand:
I've got basic function that checks if spinner is not visible.

```
`def wait_until_request_api_process_finished(self):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self._driver, 1).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(BaseLoc.spinner))
        WebDriverWait(self._driver, 10).until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located(BaseLoc.spinner))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

But, even if the spinner is not visible, selenium waits (about 8 seconds more than expected). What's the issue?

Comment: Well what is the difference between `invisibility` (did you mean `visibility_of_element_located`) and `presence`?

Comment: Indeed, didn't notice any differences between

Comment: Forget Selenium, read the name of the functions in English. There might not be a difference in you application, but the do different things.

Comment: ut, even if the spinner is not visible, selenium waits (about 8 seconds more than expected). What's the issue? - Do you have implicit waits also in your code ?

Comment: Yes, I've got implicit wait set to 10 sec. Should I remove it or rather chenge it?

Comment: @cruisepandey The issue was that I had implicit wait that prolonged waiting for the spinner to be invisible. Thank you mate!

Comment: @maxt026 : yes. Mixing them would cause a unpredictable  wait times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got few things from Selenium official docs : [here](http://Warning:%20Do%20not%20mix%20implicit%20and%20explicit%20waits.%20Doing%20so%20can%20cause%20unpredictable%20wait%20times.%20For%20example,%20setting%20an%20implicit%20wait%20of%2010%20seconds%20and%20an%20explicit%20wait%20of%2015%20seconds%20could%20cause%20a%20timeout%20to%20occur%20after%2020%20seconds.)

**Warning:**

> Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause
> unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10
> seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to
> occur after 20 seconds.

so for your this question :

But, even if the spinner is not visible, selenium waits (about 8 seconds more than expected). What's the issue?

- yes it is because you mixed both of them. Before removing implicit wait (think 8 sec really matters or more reliability of your test suite matters)

Now for this question :

```
  invisibility_of_element_located
```

basically see this internal implementation :

```
 private static boolean isInvisible(final WebElement element) {
    try {
      return !element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ignored) {
      // We can assume a stale element isn't displayed.
      return true;
    }
  }
```

so it is just checking for `isDisplayed()` internally.

Answer (score 1):

`ec.invisibility_of_element_located` waits for element invisibility.
Element can be existing on the page but be invisible.
For such element `ec.invisibility_of_element_located` will successfully return `True` and your scenario flow will continue while `until_not(ec.presence_of_element_located(element))` will throw timeout exception since the element is still existing on the page.

Comment: OK, so presence looks for the element to be in DOM only?

Comment: What do you mean by "only"? Yes, it looks for element presence, literally. There are a lot of invisible elements on most pages.

Answer (score 0):

The top statement waits until `(ec.invisibility_of_element_located(element))` happens were as the bottom would wait until `(ec.presence_of_element_located(element))` does not happen.

Side note functionally I know that doesn't make sense but that's what is being asked :)

Comment: As I understand, you mean the wait for invisibility needs the element first to be visible?

Comment: My understanding is that the first would wait until the element is found and the second would wait until the element is not found

Comment: I edited the question to highlight the problem

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second (added) part of the question:

It is possible (and probable) that the selenium script checks for invisibility before the page has finished loading. Selenium has no way of knowing if the element was visible before and now is not present in the DOM, that's why it will first wait for visibility and then invisibility.